# CSS individual cell width

Tags: css, iframe, html-table, cell, column-width

I am having some trouble applying individual cell widths. There's a 1x2 (1 row, 2 col) table in my code. The 1st cell has just links, while the other has an iframe. 
Because I had to style the first cell different, I used a selector. 
The CSS for the 1st cell/column follows:

```
.alleft {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 150px;
    }

iframe {
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
    height: 455px;
    }

table {
    width: 700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```

The relevant html may be:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td class="alleft"> 
  <h3> The Paintings of Picasso </h3>
   <a href="absinth.jpg"> The Absinth Drinker </a>
 </td>
 <td>
  <iframe src="picasso.html" name="iframe" id="iframe" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry if that looks insane! Wasn't too sure if I included too much or too little.

Comment: Relevant HTML is essential for CSS/HTML questions, please share that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code, there isn't much to go on here, so these are my guesses.

Could be one of two things:

1. Is this table contained within another div/container that has a set width? Possible that iframe + 1st cell are too wide for set width.
2. You can set a `max-width: x;` for the iframe, and a `min-width: 150px;` for the cell one. Play around with those numbers for each width and you should get something that works.

Example:

```
.alleft {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```